# Digest authentication with Guzzle

Tags: php, json, authentication, guzzle, digest

Trying to get to get JSON response from API that uses digest authentication. I am using Guzzle for the client.

This is what I have so far and doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
'base_uri' => 'https://10.1.1.1',
'timeout'  => 2.0,
]);

$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
$client->request('POST', '/json', ['auth' => ['username', 'password', 'digest']]);
```

Comment: Wich version of guzzle are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6

Comment: Has you test to pass 'verify' option in request method?, like "$client->request('POST', '/json', ['verify' => false, 'auth' => ['username', 'password', 'digest']]);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$query = '{"id":1}'; //json payload if any

$result = $client->request(
        'POST',
        'https://10.1.1.1/json', [
            'verify' => false,
            'auth' => ['username', 'password', 'digest'],
            'json' => json_decode($query, true),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if php-curl extension is installed. If not install it. For linux:

`sudo apt-get install php-curl`

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/51622772) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)